# QWindow::Minimized don't work as expected on Mac Os

Tags: qt, qml

Im trying to add a Minimized button in my app.

For now I've some problem just in Mac Os.
I tested in Linux and Win and I don't have problem.

Any ideia?

```
Rectangle {
    property bool containsMouse: titleBar.mouseX >= x + row.x && titleBar.mouseX <= x + row.x + width && titleBar.containsMouse
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    width: height
    color: containsMouse ? "#3665B3" : "#000000"

    Image {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "../images/minimizeIcon.png"
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: minimizeArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            // I can see this in Mac Os but don't work
            console.log("its work")
            appWindow.visibility = Window.Minimized
        }
   }
}
```

`appWindow` is my `ApplicationWindow {} // has all my content`
There is the link do see the ApplicationWindow: https://github.com/LetheanMovement/lethean-gui/blob/master/main.qml

I tried to use the same code to FullScreen and works well!

```
appWindow.visibility = Window.FullScreen
```

The interesting is: If I'm in a FullScreen mode my `Windows.Minimized` has the same effect as the `Windows.Windowed`

Im following this Doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html

Comment: it would be great idea if you could show the top `Window` item in your  code too. What is `appWindow` here?

Comment: @folibis I fixed my question: my `appWindows` is my `ApplicationWindows{}`.

Comment: Ok, but I've told about the code, why don't you show the `ApplicationWindows` in the code example?

Comment: @folibis I added the link to the git, is to long to add here :D

Answer (score 0):

Try appWindow.visibility = Window.Windowed before:

```
    onClicked: {
        // I can see this in Mac Os but don't work
        console.log("its work")
        appWindow.visibility = Window.Windowed
        appWindow.visibility = Window.Minimized
    }
```

Works on ArchLinux.

Comment: my code works on Linux, my problem has been in Mac Os. Tks for the help but the solution don't work for me. :(

Comment: It depends on desktop environment... works fine without Windowed on my Ubuntu as well, but on Arch it doesn't work without Windowed. I think it's some kind of qml bug

Comment: Ill let you know when a find a Mac Os solution.